# Inconsistent dimension error when plotting mesh in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, mesh

I'm new to Matlab and I want to plot a mesh. My coordinates are:

```
x = [30 34 38 40 44 48 50]

y = [1:5:20]

Z = [9.1 8.5 7.83 7.54 7.07 6.61 6.49 ; 
     14.5 8.96 8.21 7.71 7.07 6.61 6.4;
     13.37 13.4 10.2 9.4 9 7.3 7.9;
     12.09 12 12.14 11.96 13.58 14.12 14.311;
     14.97 10.77 11.87 12.4 13.62 14.19 14.94]
```

Ehen I tried to plot it in Matlab it gives following error:

> Data point coordinates have inconsistent dimension.

Comment: in Z i can see two elements without space between them.   i am talking about 8.96.8.21. add space and try again

Comment: @sera thanks a lot for pointing it out

Comment: The sizes are inconsistent. Z has 35 values, but you only have 7x4=28 x-y coordinates

Comment: If X and Y are vectors, length(X) = n and length(Y) = m, where [m,n] = size(Z)

Comment: Also, read [mcve]. How did you tried to "draw" it in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have indeed **inconsistent dimensions** as you need 5 elements in `y`. Also you need a matrix `Z`, not a vector.

The following should get you starting:

```
y = [0:5:20]

%// reshape z in case z is a vector
z = reshape(Z,numel(y),numel(x))

figure(1)
%// mesh(x,y,z)
surf(x,y,z) % colored mesh
```

[image]

Check the data sizes and adjust the reshaping according to your needs!

Answer (score 2):

In general, if `X` and `Y` are vectors, `length(X) = n` and `length(Y) = m`, where `[m,n] = size(Z)v.

In your case:

```
length(x)
7

length(y)
4
```

but

```
size(Z)

1    35
```

So you need to reshape the `Z`.

Do:

```
 x = [30 34 38 40 44 48 50]
 y = [0:5:20]
 Z = [9.1 8.5 7.83 7.54 7.07 6.61 6.49 ; 14.5 8.96 8.21 7.71 7.07 6.61 6.4; 13.37 13.4 10.2 9.4 9 7.3 7.9; 12.09 12 12.14 11.96 13.58 14.12 14.311; 14.97 10.77 11.87 12.4 13.62 14.19 14.94]
 Z = reshape(Z,numel(y),numel(x))
 mesh(x,y,Z)
```